# GRANT SELECT to all tables in postgresql

Tags: permissions, sql, postgresql, user-management

Is there a one-liner that grants the [SELECT permissions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-grant.html) to a [new user](https://serverfault.com/questions/60500/crate-a-new-read-only-user-in-postgres) postgresql?

Something that would implement the following pseudo-code:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE * TO my_new_user;
```

Answer (score 267, accepted):

I thought it might be helpful to mention that, as of 9.0, postgres does have the syntax to grant privileges on all tables (as well as other objects) in a schema:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO user;
```

To grant permissions also for tables created in the future use:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO user;
```

Here's [the link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html).

Comment: I'll upgrade soon, so this is really good news. Thanks!

Comment: Does this affect all databases on the server that use the public schema?

Comment: If I create a new table, will this user have access to the newly created table?

Comment: @GuiSim No, You have to set the `default privileges` on a schema, where ytou create the table: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Comment: @kristianp No, every database in the PG cluster has its own public schema. It affect all tables (functions) in the schema `public` for current DB you are connected to.

Comment: Note: this doesn't work on Redshift yet

Comment: I'm trying this, but I'm getting "WARNING:  no privileges were granted for xxx" for every table. This is not a particularly helpful message as it tells me nothing about what the problem is.

Comment: @szeitlin Here are two links that should help you figure that out (found by Googling "postgresql WARNING: no privileges were granted for "):

- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/24612.1210687964%40sss.pgh.pa.us
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691037/postgresql-permissions-explained

Hope that helps.

Comment: I ended up doing this (see below): https://serverfault.com/a/919358/282107

Comment: @TimH you also have to [grant schema access](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91974/92162)

Answer (score 14):

My (non-one-liner) solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

for table in `echo "SELECT schemaname || '.' || relname FROM pg_stat_user_tables;" | psql -A -t my_database_name`;
do
    echo "GRANT SELECT ON TABLE $table to my_new_user;"
    echo "GRANT SELECT ON TABLE $table to my_new_user;" | psql my_database_name
done
```

Run from the privileged user, it worked like a charm.

Comment: If you use pg_stat_user_tables instead of all_tables, you don't need your grep... Also, pass -A -t to psql to get rid of formatted output.

Comment: Note that as of Postgres 9.0, this answer's approach is doing it the hard way. In 9.x, we now have the "ON ALL" seen in [this other answer](http://serverfault.com/a/284278/142214).

Comment: this one doesn't work where table or schema names contain uppercase letters. Adding a modified version below

Answer (score 12):

This can be done with a two-step process.

1. Run this query:

   ```
   select 'grant all on '||schemaname||'.'||tablename||' to $foo;'
   from pg_tables where schemaname in ('$bar', '$baz')
   order by schemaname, tablename;
   ```

   Replacements:

   `$foo` = username you want to grant permissions for
   `$bar`, `$baz` = schemas you want to grant permissions in (can be just "public")
2. That's going to give you a list of queries that will generate the required permissions. Copy the output, paste it into another query, and execute.

Answer (score 11):

I ended up doing [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), and it worked:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;
```

Comment: very good when tables are created afterwards, and read access is meant to be granted by default

Answer (score 6):

I ended up here because my DB user saw only a few tables and not the newer ones. If this is your case, this has helped me.

1. Grant privileges to all *existing* tables:

   ```sql
   GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user;
   ```
2. Grant privileges to all *new* tables to be created in future (via default privileges):

   ```sql
   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO user;
   ```
3. You can also double-check that all tables are granted correctly.

   - Count all existing tables:

     ```sql
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
     WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND
           schemaname != 'information_schema';
     ```
   - Count all tables the user has access to:

     ```sql
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM information_schema.role_table_grants
     WHERE grantee = 'user';
     ```

   The count of last two queries must be the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used:

```
psql dbname -tc "select 'grant select on '||relname||' to readonly;' from pg_stat_user_tables" | psql dbname
```

I feel it's more natural to do formatting and where-clauses in sql..

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with postgres 8.4 and to give all privileges to a user do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

for table in `echo "SELECT schemaname||'.'||relname FROM pg_stat_all_tables WHERE schemaname NOT IN('pg_catalog','pg_toast','information_schema')" | psql -t db `;
do
    echo "grant select on table $table to my_new_user;"
    echo "grant select on table $table to my_new_user;" | psql db
done
```

Comment: In English please.

Answer (score 0):

one way to fix this is to write a stored procedure. unfortunately there is no "grant everything to all tables" command or so. 
you really need a procedure or some external shell script maybe to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The (one-liner solution) script by Adam Matan is great when there are many schema's, but it doesn't work where schema names or table names contain uppercase letters or special characters.

Modified version:

```
#!/bin/bash

for table in `echo "SELECT '\"' || schemaname || '\".\"' || relname || '\"'  FROM pg_stat_user_tables;" | psql -A -t my_database_name`;
do
    echo "GRANT SELECT ON TABLE $table to my_new_user;"
    echo "GRANT SELECT ON TABLE $table to my_new_user;" | psql my_database_name
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    schemaname text;
BEGIN
    FOR schemaname IN (SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace) LOOP
        EXECUTE 'GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ' || schemaname || ' TO user';
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: Replace "user" with the appropriate username.

Note that this query will grant the user "USAGE" and "SELECT" privileges on all tables in all schemas within the database.