# How to apply PostgreSQL "GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES" to new tables?

Tags: postgresql, user-management

As discussed in the question at [GRANT SELECT to all tables in postgresql](https://serverfault.com/questions/60508/grant-select-to-all-tables-in-postgresql), as of PG 9.0 you can mass-grant privileges on all *existing* tables to user u, using a command like:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO u;
```

Logged in as u, you can now do this to pre-existing table a:

```
SELECT * FROM a;
```

But if you now create table b and do:

```
SELECT * FROM b;
```

You get:

```
ERROR: permission denied for relation b
SQL state: 42501
```

This can be remedied by re-executing

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO u;
```

But it's a problem to have to remember to do this after each time you create a table.

Is there a way to get PostgreSQL to apply these global grants automatically to newly created tables?

~ Thanks in advance
~ Ken

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A posible solution is to alter default privileges for `u` user:

**Eg:**

```sql
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to u;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to u;
```

> **Description**
>
> `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` allows you to set the privileges that will
>   be applied to objects created in the future. (It does not affect
>   privileges assigned to already-existing objects.) Currently, only the
>   privileges for tables (including views), sequences, and functions can
>   be altered.
>
> You can change default privileges only for objects that will be
>   created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of. The
>   privileges can be set globally (i.e., for all objects created in the
>   current database), or just for objects created in specified schemas.
>   Default privileges that are specified per-schema are added to whatever
>   the global default privileges are for the particular object type.
>
> As explained under `GRANT`, the default privileges for any object type
>   normally grant all grantable permissions to the object owner, and may
>   grant some privileges to `PUBLIC` as well. However, this behavior can
>   be changed by altering the global default privileges with `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`.

see: [ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)